# How to get maximum value from joined table, which will include more than one criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created poll tables.

1. names with countries
2. questions (with ids)
3. answers (with ids)
4. responses (where users have answered to questions)

I need to get the most popular answer by country.
Saying in another way, I have to select MAX value from COUNT for each "Country"

```
SELECT Country, AnswersID, COUNT(AnswersID) AS TTL
FROM Responses 
LEFT JOIN Players AS Final ON Final.PlayersID = Responses.PlayersID
GROUP BY AnswersID, Country
```

This code gives output like:

```
Country | AnswersID | Total
-----------------------------
xxx     |     2     | 5
-------------------------------
xxx     |     1     | 2
-------------------------------
yyy     |     2     | 3
------------------------------
yyy     |     1     | 2
```

---

What I expect:

```
xxx 2 5
--------------------
yyy 2 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to assign a number to each record ordered by the count descending per country.

```
SELECT country,
       answerid,
       ttl
       FROM (SELECT country,
                    answersid,
                    count(answersid) ttl,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY country
                                       ORDER BY count(answersid) DESC) r
                    FROM responses 
                         LEFT JOIN players final
                                   ON final.playersid = responses.playersid
                    GROUP BY answersid,
                             country)
       WHERE r = 1;
```

Using `row_number()` will only get one record per country even if two or more answers share the maximum count. If you want to show all the records with the maximum, you can use `rank()` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Worked. What if I have 2 countries with maximum value? For example country xxx has 5 responses for id 1 and id 2

Comment: @LevonBadalyan: Read the last paragraph of my answer. I already addressed that.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the country is assigned to the player, not the response.  If so, you don't need an outer join (and certainly not one that starts with `responses`):

```
SELECT p.Country, r.AnswersID, COUNT(*) AS TTL
FROM Responses JOIN
     Players p
     ON p.PlayersID = r.PlayersID
GROUP BY p.Country, r.AnswersID
```

Then you can use window functions to get the highest total per country.  Use `rank()` to get all top answers when there are ties; use `row_number()` to get only one row:

```
SELECT Country, AnswersID, TTL
FROM (SELECT p.Country, r.AnswersID, COUNT(*) AS TTL,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY p.Country ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Responses r JOIN
           Players p
           ON p.PlayersID = r.PlayersID
      GROUP BY p.Country, r.AnswersID
     ) c
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

In statistics, this most common value is referred to as the *mode*.